# How to install a Chrome extension with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, google-chrome

I have to install a Chrome extension using C/C++.

I tried to copy the whole folder of a extension in C:\Users[login_name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions. After copying it I deleted the extension from Chrome and then pasted the extension folder back to its own place but it doesn't get installed. How can I install a Chrome extension without using the Chrome browser? I want to install the extension using C/C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome supports the following alternative extension installation methods:

- Using a preferences JSON file (for macOS X and Linux only)
- Using the Windows registry (for Windows only)

source:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/external_extensions/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).